# $compile dynamically create angular element, using $rootScope in a factory

Tags: angularjs

I have a method in a factory that dynamically adds controls to a menu. It needs to be created dynamically because depending on the user the controls will be different. I have read through the posts on StackOverflow and seen suggestions such as create a separate directive or compiling the element *after* it has been appended. I am having trouble wrapping my head around these solutions.

Here is the function:

```
factory.addCtrl = (name, icon) ->
    ctrlCenter = angular.element("#control-container")
    ctrl = angular.element("<div ng-click=\"togglePanel('bottom', '#{name}')\">#{icon} #{name}</div>")
    ctrlCenter.append(ctrl)
    $compile(ctrlCenter)($rootScope)
```

I also wonder if injecting `$rootScope` just for compile to work is a 'good' solution? Or does it mean I am using it incorrectly and it really should be happening within the controller? The element is created but the `ng-click` function doesn't actually work meaning it wasn't fully compiled.

Answer (score 0):

if I got what your asking you want to dynamically add code to your html that will be compiled so you will be able to use ng-click and so on....
I created a directive for that in my project...It might help you out:

```
app.directive('ngHtmlCompile',function ($compile) {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
               // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
              return scope.$eval(attrs.ngHtmlCompile);
            },
            function(value) {
              // when the 'compile' expression changes
              // assign it into the current DOM
              element.html(value);

              // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
              // scope.
              // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
              // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
              $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        );
    };
});
```

and in the html:

```
<div ng-html-compile="sprAnswerHTML"></div>
```

then you can in the controller for example add :

```
$scope.sprAnswerHTML =
     '<h2>{{ltgLabels.SPR_QUESTION_ANSWER}}</h2>';
```

naturally this will also work for all angular functions and directives/events

hope this helps

Comment: `<div ng-html-compile="sprAnswerHTML"></div>` needs to be created in a factory though (which brings us back to the first problem that I can't compile it within a factory), I can't have it in a view since I loop through an array and create a layer for each one. I will try it out though.

Comment: Thinking about it, I'm not sure manipulating the dom from any place but a controller is good practice... I would advise that all dom manipulation be done in controllers

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Angular` best practice is only manipulating the `DOM` from directives, not controllers.

Comment: I meant any place like factory like you are using... Of course Directives... thats what they are for, sorry for the misunderstanding.